# React-Native : useState to update object inside array

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a list of items, when one is clicked, it navigates to a modal which displays a list of options.
I am trying to increment the counter inside each option, it works as intended BUT when I exit the modal screen and go back to it, the options counter are not reseted.

```
const myOptions = [
  { id: '001', name: 'option 001', counter: 0 },
  { id: '002', name: 'option 002', counter: 0 },
];

function ModalScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(myOptions);

  let tempArr = [...myOptions]; 
  // Array where I increment the counter, before passing it to setOptions(tempArr)

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // because of let tempArr = [...myOptions]; changes in tempArr are copied 
      in myOptions. I want to reset myOptions when I exit the component
      console.log(options); 
      console.log(myOptions) // both output are identical
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 15 }}>
        Click on an option to increment counter by 1
      </Text>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={item => item.name}
        extraData={tempArr}
        data={options}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              tempArr[index].counter++;
              setOptions(tempArr);
            }}>
            <Text>
              {item.name} - counter: {item.counter}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I did a demo here :
https://snack.expo.io/@oliviermtl/carefree-marshmallows

I spent my day trying to figure out this one... Let me know if something needs more explanation
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code you’re having trouble with in addition to the link you shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
  useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
          console.log(options); 
          console.log(myOptions)
        };
      }, []);
```

to

```
 useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      myOptions[0].quantity = 0;
      myOptions[1].quantity = 0;
    };
  },[]);
```

What I was doing is that changing quantity values to 0, whenever user closes or comes back out from modal.
Hope this helps!

Comment: So easy and obvious, I have also been trying to get myOptions to its original values (hence the useEffect return) and did not even think about this solution. Thank you !